# Way to set the value of Image Position (patient) tag of DICOM slice

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vtk

Is there any way to set the value of `Image Position (patient)` tag of DICOM slice using DCMTK.

**Detailed Explanation**

I have this

[image]

In this window, the user needs to enter the x,y and z values of the `ImagePosition(patient)` tag in the DICOM slice which the user need to find.

I will take those x,y,z values in some variable say, `xval,yval,zval`.

And now I need to **set** these values in the DICOMImageReader `reader`  or **using any VTK variable (like vtkMarchingSquares or vtkClipper or vtkPlane ..etc)** so that I can either **show or clip** where the corresponding slice is, in the 3D rendered output.

Is my question clear? Is there any possible way?

**What I tried**

*1.To clip the corresponding slice in 3D rendered output*

I  tried using `vtkClipPolyData1 clipper` like below

```
plane->SetOrigin(0,0,0);//vtkPlane//
plane->SetNormal(xval,yval,zval);
clipper->SetClipFunction(plane);
```

But this is not working.
I also tried[don't know whether this is right or wrong]

```
  double a=(double)(xval)/100;
  double b=(double)(yval)/100;
  double c =(double)(zval)/100;
 clipper->SetNormal(a,b,c);
```

but this code is not clipping the exact position,it is clipped at somewhere else.

*2.To show the corresponding slice in 3d rendered output*

```
 vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable> bwLut =vtkSmartPointer<vtkLookupTable>::New();
 bwLut->SetTableRange (0, 2000);
 bwLut->SetSaturationRange (0, 0);
 bwLut->SetHueRange (0, 0);
 bwLut->SetValueRange (0, 1);
 bwLut->Build();

  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors> sagittalColors =
  vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageMapToColors>::New();
  sagittalColors->SetInputConnection(reader->GetOutputPort());
  sagittalColors->SetLookupTable(bwLut);
  sagittalColors->Update();

vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor> sagittal =vtkSmartPointer<vtkImageActor>::New();
  sagittal->GetMapper()>SetInputConnection(sagittalColors->GetOutputPort());
  sagittal->SetPosition(xval,yval,zval);//this is where i put the values//
```

Anybody could help pleaseee?

Comment: Your question seems to be related to VTK and not to the DCMTK. If you'd have access to the DICOM dataset stored within the DCMTK (i.e. an instance of DcmDataset or DcmItem), you could use the DcmItem::putAndInsertString() method to replace the value of Image Position (Patient).

Comment: I know vtk but i never have used DCMTK in it.So i don't know anything about DCMTK .I either have to show or clip the slice .is it possible in any other method sir?

Comment: Do you know any other method sir

Comment: Marking this question as "applicable to a large audience" is deeply inappropriate.  You are endangering the life of a human being by getting this wrong, you cannot reasonably expect anybody here to be aware of such grave concerns.  Discuss this with a knowledgeable person inside the company you work for, somebody that is aware of the kind of regulation and liability that applies here.  In general, if you don't have a good interface to the radio-logical equipment that can provide patient position info then you should not do this at all.

Comment: oh i dont know about that.I will delete the question after bounty is over